# Greasemonkey-like Firefox plugin for automatic browsing

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, greasemonkey, mechanize

Is there a plug-in for Firefox that would allow user's Javascript code like Greasemonkey and be able to browse from page to page?

I'd like to write a script to:

1. Log in to a website.
2. Follow several links.
3. Make a GET request to that host periodically with given data and time intervals.
4. Make a POST request based on the results of the previous in-loop requests.

Now I use Python's mechanize for a browser so I'm looking for something with similar (maybe not that rich) functionality within Firefox. Do you have experience with that type of things? What should I check out?

Comment: Your question is off-topic for SO. If you [edit] your question according to the instructions [here](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) our sister site [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be able to help you out after that. If you're done editing flag for a mod asking for migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) - which has an interface for recording and running tests inside the browser but can also export tests in many languages including Python for running as a suite in the SeleniumRC tool.

Or

[Chickenfoot](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/index.php) (You'll probably need to use setTimeout for the repeating requests.)

[image]
<sub>(source: [mit.edu](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/images/simple_screenshot.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You also have [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863)

The software's description on Mozilla Addons says :

> Automate Firefox. Record and replay
>   repetitious work. If you love the
>   Firefox web browser, but are tired of
>   repetitive tasks like visiting the
>   same sites every days, filling out
>   forms, and remembering passwords, then
>   iMacros for Firefox is the solution
>   you’ve been dreaming of! Whatever you
>   do with Firefox, iMacros can automate
>   it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
<sub>(source: [extjs.com](http://extjs.com/blog/images/gxt/selenium/selenium-rc.png))</sub>

I would recommend [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). It comes as a Java command line tool and allows you to remote-control both Firefox, IE and Safari. Although it is officially a browser based web-testing tool, it can be very useful for crawling and scraping AJAX-based web applications and for all sort of automated tasks otherwise difficult to accomplish with non graphical HTTP clients such as Curl, Hpricot and Mechanize.

Moreover, it's widely spread, has an API for most popular programming languages (including python), and allows you inject custom javascript code within web-pages.

PS:
Documentation is [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html)